# Using Linq to find the line that matches an entry

Tags: c#, linq

I have config file with the following format:

```
keydemo1,this is a demo version of the software

keyprod1,this is production version of the software
```

Following is the C# code to fetch the relevant line based on the key. So if I pass: `GetEntryFromConfigFile ("config.ini", "keyprod1")`, I am expecting the entire line below back:

```
"keyprod1, this is production version of the software"
```

But, it is not working. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
public static string GetEntryFromConfigFile(string fileName, string entryToFind)
{
    //var m = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.IndexOf(entryToFind) != -1);
    //m = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.ToLower().Contains(entryToFind.ToLower())).ToList();
    var m = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.ToLower().IndexOf(entryToFind.ToLower()) > -1).ToList();
    //m returns 0 count;
    return m.ToString();        
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or just no results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `StartsWith()` or `IndexOf()` is not a good idea. What if you have two lines in your file starting with `keydemo1` and `keydemo11`?

This is what I would do:

```
public static string GetEntryFromConfigFile(string fileName, string entryToFind)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filename).FirstOrDefault(line => line.Split(',')[0].Equals(entryToFind, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mod: File.ReadLines(fileName).FirstOrDefault(line => line.Split('^')[0].ToLower().StartsWith(entryToFind.ToLower(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do the following:

```
  var entry = File.ReadLines(fileName).FirstOrDefault(l => l.IndexOf(entryToFind,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

This will retrieve one entry. It will check if a line contains the given string. It ignores casing and culture settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static string GetEntryFromConfigFile(string fileName, string entryToFind)
{
    var m = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.StartsWith(entryToFind, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault(); 
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetEntryFromConfigFile(string fileName, string entryToFind)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filename).FirstOrDefault(line => line.ToLower().Contains(entryToFind.ToLower()));
}
```